# Exception during RSA decrypt: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, badpaddingexception

I'm trying to decrypt a password in RSA format, but it's returning exception

```
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:308)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:255)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.a(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
```

When crypting and decrypting in sequence, it works normally.

It seems that I am having a problem with private and public Keys, any evidence of that in the code bellow?

Thanks

**Client:**

```
    public class TestarDescripto { 

    public static void main(String args []) throws Exception{ 

        String valorAberto = "pass123";

        System.out.println("open password  - > " + valorAberto );

        String valorCriptoRSA = "B5URvvSpoR7XaWLrYsbd6WQVNZG2haqeijuP8LzxtBigwuCG/5s4XO19wsGhtsFFfmnJ3vvqSS3TQ3DQnoQ3jVM8/sF7FqxW8u/RMJ5H/rJNSGAENDlA4U8WleQtP0S8ES8tONOuCdsqVLsbaYX/ep8naA2cEAmHYTFz30Jw9ylsPmvomlHCay14be9h2HkbxjzH/uuqk3J/xuMsPixITNpTgirh1gJVDZ1is9qPAJmpITmaxgCqwhFDuuYeMyVGYkVx/0e3hOWEStAAKlTy+lCgcc2GbJPwZysd08sDLVOoPwtDxzJ0SP0hyDrazs+cv9gKbBJ4OFxeTuBqf5AhEw==";

        System.out.println("Valor criptografado RSA - > " + valorCriptoRSA);

        String valorDesriptoRSA = TestarDescripto.executarDescriptoRSA(valorCriptoRSA);
        System.out.println("Valor descriptografado RSA - > " + valorDesriptoRSA);

        System.out.println("Senha aberta == Senha descriptografada - > " + valorAberto.equals(valorDesriptoRSA));

    } 

    public static String executarDescriptoRSA(String valorCriptografado ) throws CriptografadorException {

        Criptografador criptografador = CriptografadorFactory.getInstance().getCriptografador(CriptografadorTipo.RSA);

        CriptografadorBeanIn beanDesc = new CriptografadorBeanIn();

        beanDesc.setSenhaCriptografadaStringBytesBase64(valorCriptografado);

        CriptografadorBeanOut beanDescript = criptografador.decrypt(beanDesc);

        String senhaDescriptografada = new String (beanDescript.getSenhaAberta());

        return senhaDescriptografada;
}
}
```

Server:

```
public class CriptografadorRSA extends CriptografadorSimetrico{ 

private static final String UTF_8 = "UTF8"; 
private static final int KEY_SIZE = 2048; 
private static final String RSA = "RSA";

private KeyPairGenerator KEY_PAIR_GENERATOR; 
private Cipher CIPHER;

private static final SecureRandom SECURE_RANDOM = new SecureRandom();

private KeyFactory RSA_KEY_FACTORY; 
private byte[] publicEncode;
private byte[] privateEncode;
private PublicKey rsaPubKey; 
private PrivateKey rsaPriKey; 

CriptografadorRSA () throws CriptografadorException {

    try {

        KEY_PAIR_GENERATOR = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(RSA);

        KEY_PAIR_GENERATOR.initialize(KEY_SIZE, SECURE_RANDOM);

        RSA_KEY_FACTORY = KeyFactory.getInstance(RSA);

        CIPHER = Cipher.getInstance(RSA);
    } 
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException  exception) {

        super.errorHandler(CriptografadorRSA.class,exception, null);
    }
    catch (NoSuchPaddingException exception) {

        super.errorHandler(CriptografadorRSA.class,exception, null);
    }

    String PUBLIC_KEY = CritografadorPropertiesUtil.getInstance().getPropriedade("PUBLIC_KEY");

    String PRIVATE_KEY = CritografadorPropertiesUtil.getInstance().getPropriedade("PRIVATE_KEY");

    File publicFile = new File(PUBLIC_KEY); 

    File privateFile = new File(PRIVATE_KEY); 

    try {

        toFile(publicFile, privateFile);

        publicEncode = readFile(publicFile);

        privateEncode = readFile(privateFile);

    } 
    catch (IOException exception) {

        super.errorHandler(CriptografadorRSA.class,exception, null);
    } 

    try {

        rsaPubKey = toPublicKey(publicEncode);

        rsaPriKey = toPrivateKey(privateEncode);
    } 
    catch (InvalidKeySpecException exception) {

        super.errorHandler(CriptografadorRSA.class,exception, null);
    } 
}

@Override
public CriptografadorBeanOut encrypt(CriptografadorBeanIn bean) throws CriptografadorException {

        byte[] cripto;

        CriptografadorBeanOut out = new CriptografadorBeanOut();

        try {

            cripto = cripto(rsaPubKey, bean.getPassPlainText());

            out.setPassCrypto(cripto);

            String encodeBase64String = Base64.encodeBase64String(cripto);

            out.setPassCryptoStringBytesBase64(encodeBase64String);
        } 
        catch (InvalidKeyException exception) {

            super.errorHandler(CriptografadorRSA.class,exception, null);
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException exception) {

            super.errorHandler(CriptografadorRSA.class,exception, null);

        } 
        catch (IllegalBlockSizeException exception) {

            super.errorHandler(CriptografadorRSA.class,exception, null);

        } 
        catch (BadPaddingException exception) {

            super.errorHandler(CriptografadorRSA.class,exception, null);
        } 

        return out;
}

@Override
public CriptografadorBeanOut decrypt(CriptografadorBeanIn bean) throws CriptografadorException {

    byte[] descryptByte;

    CriptografadorBeanOut out = new CriptografadorBeanOut();

    try {

        byte[] byteValue = bean.getCryptoPass();

        if (byteValue == null || byteValue.length ==0){

            if (bean.getCryptoPassStringBytesBase64() != null ) {

                byteValue = Base64.decodeBase64(bean.getCryptoPassStringBytesBase64());
            }   
        }

        descryptByte = passDecrypt(rsaPriKey, byteValue);

        try {

            String descriptoString = new String (descryptByte, UTF_8);

            out.setPassPlainText(descriptoString);

        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException exception) {

            super.errorHandler(CriptografadorRSA.class,exception, null);
        }
    } 
    catch (InvalidKeyException exception) {

        super.errorHandler(CriptografadorRSA.class,exception, null);
    } 
    catch (IllegalBlockSizeException exception) {

        super.errorHandler(CriptografadorRSA.class,exception, null);
    } 
    catch (BadPaddingException exception) {

        super.errorHandler(CriptografadorRSA.class,exception, null);
    }

    return out;
}


private PublicKey toPublicKey(byte[] encoded) throws InvalidKeySpecException{ 

    X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded); 

    return RSA_KEY_FACTORY.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
}

private PrivateKey toPrivateKey(byte[] encoded) throws InvalidKeySpecException{

    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded); 

    return RSA_KEY_FACTORY.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec); 
}

private byte[] passDecrypt(PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] cipherText) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

    CIPHER.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey); 

    return CIPHER.doFinal(cipherText); 
} 

private byte[] cripto(PublicKey publicKey,String word) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

    CIPHER.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

    return CIPHER.doFinal(word.getBytes(UTF_8)); 


}

private KeyPair createKeyPair() {

    return KEY_PAIR_GENERATOR.generateKeyPair(); 
}

private void toFile(File publicFile, File privateFile) throws IOException {

    KeyPair keyPair = createKeyPair();

    FileOutputStream  streamPrivate = new FileOutputStream(privateFile);

    streamPrivate.write(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded()); 

    FileOutputStream  streamPublic = new FileOutputStream(publicFile);

    streamPublic.write(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded()); 
}

private byte[] readFile(File file) throws IOException{

    byte[] datas=new byte[(int)file.length()];

    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);

    stream.read(datas); 

    return datas;
}
```

}

Comment: as a general rule, it is good to put your exception stack trace on the ticket to give us context within your code.

Comment: Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero
 at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:308)
 at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:255)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.a(DashoA13*..)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)

Comment: this should go on the question, not as a comment.  thanks.

Comment: WTF is `CriptografadorFactory`? :) Anyway bad padding means you truncated or appended data or corrupted some bytes (for example wrong encoding) or you use wrong parameters or keys.. Since your code is hard to read, I cant be more specific. Can you try to prune it to the absolute minimum?